# Restric row selection based on indexpath

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to restrict my `didselectrowat` option, so that if I have a variable called `loggedInUser`...

`if loggedInUser = "master"` allow the function as it is...
`if loggedInUser = "bobby"` only allow this function to occur where `indexPath = "bobby"`

How can I implement this without replicating all of my code.

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let user = Userlist[indexPath.row]

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Master Function", message: "Edit \(user.Username!) like a Boss", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let updateaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default){(_)in

            blah blah blah
        }
        let deleteaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default){(_)in
            blah blah blah

        }

        alert.addAction(updateaction)
        alert.addAction(deleteaction)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could accomplish it, with the following code snippet:

```
if user.Username == loggedInUser || loggedInUser == "Master"
```